# How to compute in R the minimum number of observations to be removed to achieve complete separability between 2 groups

Tags: r, classification, overlap

Problem: to compute in R the minimum number of observations to be removed to achieve complete separation between 2 groups (Nout).

Eg:

```
df<-data.frame(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10,4,5.5,6,6.5,8,9,12),c(rep("a",8),rep("b",7)))
colnames(df)<-c("Values","Groups")
df
boxplot(df[,1]~df[,2])
points(df[,1]~df[,2],cex=2)
abline(6.2,0)
```

[See the plot produced with the above code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evluT.png).

In that case, removing the 2 higher values of a and 3 lowest values of b gives a possible solution with Nout = 2 + 3 = 5. 
This corresponds to treshold value of for example 6.2 (red line on the plot)

Is there a R tool to easily compute that automatically?

I found 2 similar tools in R ARCHIVE:

- Ncomplete package:
  https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/ncomplete/ (for
  complete separation)
- Noverlap package :
  https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/noverlap/ (for
  quasi-complete separation)

They seem however not validated (code start by "NO WARRANTY", and are not in active R package list)

Answer (score 0):

I think `median` is useful here, although you need to apply it differently based on the 3 general cases you'll encounter

```
case 1: distribution of values do not overlap
case 2: distribution of values in 1 group completely overlaps with distribution of values in other group
case 3: distribution of values partially overlap (the data example you gave)
```

How you'll need to apply the `median` in the different cases follows

```
case 1: median value of all values
case 2: median value of all values
case 3: median value of only overlapping values
```

Your data and your plot function

```
plotfun <- function(df) {
    with(df, boxplot(Values~Groups))
    with(df, points(Values~Groups, cex=2))
}

df<-data.frame(Values = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10,4,5.5,6,6.5,8,9,12),
            Groups = c(rep("a",8),rep("b",7)))
df
plotfun(df)
```

The workhorse function is `myfun`. It will determine which of the 3 cases is relevant, and then apply the median accordingly. You can supply an additional argument `unitofchange` in case your values are not integers. That is, perhaps you're dealing with data that increments by `0.1`.

```
library(dplyr)
myfun <- function(df, unitofchange=1) {
    unitofchange <- unitofchange / 10
    require(dplyr)
    summarydf <- df %>%
            group_by(Groups) %>%
            summarise(min = min(Values), max = max(Values)) %>%
            arrange(min)

    if (summarydf$max[1] < summarydf$min[2]) {
        # Case 1: distributions do not overlap
        ans <- list(Break = median(df$Values), Nout = 0)
    } else if (summarydf$max[1] > summarydf$max[2]) {
        # Case 2: one distribution is completely between other distribution
        ans <- list(Break = median(df$Values))
        ans[["Break"]] <- modifyiftie(df, unitofchange, ans[["Break"]])
        ans["Nout"] <- sum(df$Values < ans[["Break"]])
    } else {
        # Case 3: distributions partially overlap
        subset_df <- df %>%
                filter(between(Values, summarydf$min[2], summarydf$max[1]))
        ans <- list(Break = median(subset_df$Values))
        ans[["Break"]] <- modifyiftie(df, unitofchange, ans[["Break"]])
        ans["Nout"] <- sum(subset_df$Values[subset_df$Groups == summarydf$Groups[1]] > ans[["Break"]],
                    subset_df$Values[subset_df$Groups == summarydf$Groups[1]] < ans[["Break"]])
    }
    return(ans)
}
```

I also included another function `modifyiftie` in cases like the example you gave where the separation value is found in both groups

```
modifyiftie <- function(df, unitofchange, b) {
    require(dplyr)
    tie <- df %>%
        group_by(Groups) %>%
        filter(Values == b)

    if (nrow(tie) > 0 & all(unique(tie$Groups) %in% unique(df$Groups))) {       # tie is true
        return(b + unitofchange)
    } else {
        return(b)
    }
}
```

Output of the 3 different cases

Case 3: Your data

```
df<-data.frame(Values = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10,4,5.5,6,6.5,8,9,12),
            Groups = c(rep("a",8),rep("b",7)))
df
myfun(df)

# $Break
# [1] 6.1

# $Nout
# [1] 5
```

Case 1: Distributions do not overlap

```
set.seed(1)
df<-data.frame(Values = c(runif(10)*10, (runif(10)*10)+10),
            Groups = rep(c("a","b"), each=10))
plotfun(df)
myfun(df)

# $Break
# [1] 10.60616

# $Nout
# [1] 0
```

Case 2: Distribution of one group falls in between distribution of other group

```
set.seed(1)
df<-data.frame(Values = c((runif(10)*5)+5, runif(10)*20),
            Groups = rep(c("a","b"), each=10))
plotfun(df)
myfun(df)

# $Break
# [1] 8.22478

# $Nout
# [1] 10
```